# Monit Measure Responsetime for http requests wrong status speed failed by responsetime < limit

Tags: http, monit, response-time

using Monit to monitor http response and responsetime

strangewise monit shows **speed failed** even responsetime is lower than limit.

`monit status:      Speed failed`
 `Port response time  158.118 ms to 127.0.0.1:8086/fhem?detail=monit_test type TCP/IP protocol HTTP`

`Port   If failed [127.0.0.1]:8086/fhem?detail=monit_test type TCP/IP protocol HTTP with timeout 4 s and responsetime equal to 500 ms then alert`

so I am confused why status is failed.

also wonding about the message port: ...saying responsetime equal....

config file is like
`check process fhemPort8086RT with pidfile /opt/fhem/fhem.pid

if failed
host 127.0.0.1
port 8086
protocol http
request "/fhem?detail=monit_test"
responsetime 500 ms
timeout 4 seconds
then alert`

what am I missing?

did not find anythin in manual about responsetime using <

I would expect a correct status

as responsetime is lower than limit set

update:
I also added another check with responsetime < 1s.

monit status showing

```
Port response time  315.675 ms to 127.0.0.1:8086/fhem?detail=monit_test type TCP/IP protocol HTTP
```

Data collected  Thu, 05 Oct 2023 16:38:25
Existence   If doesn't exist then restart
Port    If failed [127.0.0.1]:8086/fhem?detail=monit_test type TCP/IP protocol HTTP with timeout 4 s and responsetime **less** than 1 s then alert

Now I am seeing a more locial port message responsetime less, but even  condition is fulfilled, overall status is :
**speed error**.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion only.

> also wonding about the message port: ...saying responsetime equal....

You can see some additional information about the used/defined rules by using "monit -t -vv" to test your configuration and show the internal information also.

Based on your check, "responsetime 500 ms timeout 4 seconds then alert" is translated to "with timeout 4 s and responsetime equal to 500 ms then alert".

From my understanding you are interesing in defining something like
"with timeout 4 s and responsetime greater than 500 ms then alert"
therefore you should use "responsetime > 500 ms with timeout 4 seconds then alert".

Based on your modified definition you use "with timeout 4 s and responsetime less than 500 ms then alert", you send an alert if the timeout is below 500ms but you will get an alert if the response time is above 500ms, I think.